# Manipulating attachments with InboxSDK

Tags: javascript, google-inbox, inboxsdk

Is there any way to manipulate/access message attachments using the [InboxSDK](http://inboxsdk.com)?

I see in the docs that you can access recipients and body content, but there's no mention of attachments in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get attachments with the Gmail API itself: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get